# Why don't the push_back in vector<> and list<> containers return the reference to the inserted element?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I realize I can get the <strike>iterator</strike> reference by calling `back()` but why not return it with `push_back()` as well? Is it for performance reasons? Or is it due to exception safety (similar to why `pop_back()` doesn't return the popped value)? In either case, please explain.

Comment: `back` doesn't give you an iterator. It gives you a reference to the last item. You can then take the `&` of that item, but this isn't an iterator. I think the only way to get an iterator to the last item of a list is to do use `rbegin()` or `end() - 1`. (Maybe that needs to be `auto x = l.end(); --x;`)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Thanks for pointing that out, rephrased the question.

Comment: This question is specially relevant since C++17, where emplace_back and emplace_front (std::list) do return a reference to the inserted element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Various `insert` functions return an iterator for a very simple reason: the caller does not necessarily know how to get an iterator to that element. `map::insert` and `set::insert` return one because otherwise, the caller would have to search for the element.

When you do a `vector::push_back`, you *know* where the inserted element is. It's `--vector.end()`. You don't have to search for it; it's *always* that location. You can get it in constant time, and pretty quick constant time at that.

So there's really no point in returning something that the user already knows.

Comment: +1. This argument makes sense. `push_back` pushes element at the back, so the caller pretty much knows where the element goes, and what the iterator would be.

Comment: The user knows *and can get in constant time*.

Comment: @NicolBolas You have a point. I just assumed the OP would like to retrieve an iterator to get a reference to the object inserted. I don't see any other real use case otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is an official reason but the most immediate that comes to my mind is performance.  If you look at the majority of uses of `push_back` and `push_front` the return value is not used.  Where an element is pushed is not so important as that it's pushed.

Why return a non-free value that is almost never used?

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler throw it away at compile time as it can clearly see the returned iterator is not being used?

Comment: @Samaursa In general if a given method produces a return value the compiler is not at liberty to optimize away the creation of that value. It could have side effects depended upon by the caller / callee.  It can certainly discard the result but that doesn't remove the overhead of creation

Comment: @Samaursa The compiler can't throw it away unless the call is inlined in which case it might be able to if it can prove that the construction of the return value has no side effects.

Comment: @Samaursa: The iterator still have to be constructed from within `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `vector` provides an `insert` method that does return an iterator to the inserted position. The standard is consistent in that `push_back` doesn't return a value but some forms of `insert` will, when available and appropriate.